# Hall's marriage theorem for infinite system of finite sets

Tags: combinatorics

We have proved the Hall's marriage theorem for the finite system of finite sets; now I would like to show that it holds even for infinite system of finite sets.

I have been trying to prove this myself for quite a while, but did not succeed. Can anyone provide a sketch of the proof?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the theorem known to be true for infinite systems of finite sets?

Comment: I suspect yes; but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the Cowan-Engeler Lemma. I put up a full proof on [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Hall%27s_Marriage_Theorem/General_Set)